# Assignment problem

Tags: linux

[image]

I've tried

cp ~stenton/../cambridge/security/parking  stenton/parking2

could someone help me out and let me know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current directory `stenton` .

`stenton` and the parent directory for `security` which is `cambridge` are on the same level.

So if need to access anything under `cambridge`, you'd issue:

`ls -l ../cambridge`.

From then on, if you needed to complete the task (using only relative paths):

you'd issue:
`cp ../cambridge/security/parking ./parking2`
The final "./" means "the current directory".

You could omit the `./` and simply use:
`cp ../cambridge/security/parking parking2`.